# 2 lists of nodes for a procedure call

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need 2 lists of nodes for the call of my procedure. The following query doesnt work because the first list is not defined (overwritten with the second collect I guess). I already tried a lot of queries but somehow im missing the right one. I think this one is showing what I actually want to achieve.

```
MATCH (n:NODE)
WHERE n.NODE_ELID='BLOCK1' OR n.NODE_ELID='BLOCK2'
WITH COLLECT(n) AS blockNodes
MATCH (m:NODE)
WHERE m.NODE_ELID='MUST1' OR m.NODE_ELID='MUST2'
WITH COLLECT(m) AS mustNodes
MATCH (from:NODE{NODE_ELID:'START'}),(to:NODE{NODE_ELID:'END'})
CALL example.aStar(from,to,'CONNECTED_TO','DISTANCE','COORD_X','COORD_Y',blockNodes,mustNodes) yield path as path, weight as weight
RETURN path, weight
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass along `blockNodes` in line 6:

```
WITH blockNodes, COLLECT(m) AS mustNodes
```

The point here is that `WITH` does many things: it performs projection, aggregation, filtering (as `WITH` clauses can have their own `WHERE` clause) and ordering/limiting. See [the docs on `WITH`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/#query-with) for more details.